# map undefined Gutenberg Block

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

```
/**
 * BLOCK: display-mobile-advertising
 *
 * Registering a basic block with Gutenberg.
 * Simple block, renders and saves the same content without any interactivity.
 */

//  Import CSS.

import { TextareaControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import { useState } from '@wordpress/element';


import './editor.scss';
import './style.scss';

const { __ } = wp.i18n; // Import __() from wp.i18n
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks; // Import registerBlockType() from wp.blocks

/**
 * Register: aa Gutenberg Block.
 *
 * Registers a new block provided a unique name and an object defining its
 * behavior. Once registered, the block is made editor as an option to any
 * editor interface where blocks are implemented.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/
 * @param  {string}   name     Block name.
 * @param  {Object}   settings Block settings.
 * @return {?WPBlock}          The block, if it has been successfully
 *                             registered; otherwise `undefined`.
 */
registerBlockType( 'cgb/block-display-mobile-advertising', {
    // Block name. Block names must be string that contains a namespace prefix. Example: my-plugin/my-custom-block.
    title: __( 'display-mobile-advertising - CGB Block' ), // Block title.
    icon: 'shield', // Block icon from Dashicons → https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/.
    category: 'common', // Block category — Group blocks together based on common traits E.g. common, formatting, layout widgets, embed.
    keywords: [
        __( 'display-mobile-advertising — CGB Block' ),
        __( 'CGB Example' ),
        __( 'create-guten-block' ),
    ],

    /**
     * The edit function describes the structure of your block in the context of the editor.
     * This represents what the editor will render when the block is used.
     *
     * The "edit" property must be a valid function.
     *
     * @link https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/block-edit-save/
     *
     * @param {Object} props Props.
     * @returns {Mixed} JSX Component.
     */
    attributes: {
        inputData: {
            type: 'string',
        },
        advertisers: {
            type: 'array'
        }
    },



    edit: ( props ) => {


        function updateData(event){
            props.setAttributes({inputData: event.target.value})
        }

        function addNewItem  ()  {
            const advertisers = [...attributes.advertisers];
            advertisers.push(attributes.inputData);
            props.setAttributes({advertisers: advertisers });
            props.setAttributes({inputData: ""});
          };


        return (

            React.createElement("div", null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Write your text here"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
                type: "text",
                value: props.attributes.inputData,
                onChane: updateData
              }), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("button", {
                onClick: addNewItem
              }, "Add Item"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("ul", null, props.attributes.advertisers.map(advertiser => {
                return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("li", null, advertiser);
              })))



        );
    },

    /**
     * The save function defines the way in which the different attributes should be combined
     * into the final markup, which is then serialized by Gutenberg into post_content.
     *
     * The "save" property must be specified and must be a valid function.
     *
     * @link https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/block-edit-save/
     *
     * @param {Object} props Props.
     * @returns {Mixed} JSX Frontend HTML.
     */
    save: ( props ) => {
        // React.createElement("div", null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h1", null, props.attributes.inputData));
        return null;
    },
} );
```

For whatever reason I can not run the map function on advertisers, I am trying to implement something like to do list inside WordPress admin page, To have input which adds data to advertisers and this array should be shown on edit page.

Comment: "I can not run the map function" means what exactly? If there's an error, it's helpful to include that in the question.

Comment: There was no error, I solved the problem this was happening because for some reason .map function could not reach the array inside attributes, so instead of using these props.attributes.advertisers.map I created variable  const data = props.attributes.advertisers; outside return statement and then I could reach array like this data.map

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to make this work, for some strange reason you can not reach an array inside attributes so I had to create variable outside of return statement like this data = props.attributes.advertisers; and then I could reach the map function with variable data.map(....). also I have added

```
advertisers: {
            type: 'array',
            ///this also can be a problem it will be better to add empty array
           default: []
 }
```